# If the Handshaking Theorem holds for a sequence of vertices, does there always exist a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I was given a bunch of degree sequences and had to determine whether or not a graph was possible.
I used the Handshaking Theorem and concluded there was no graph if the sum of degrees was odd.
However, a lot of the times it summed to an even number but there was no *simple* graph for the sequence.
All the time there was a non-simple graph, however.
Will there always be a non-simple graph?

Comment: There is not always a simple graph (or even a non-simple graph).  The [Erdős-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) describes when a degree sequence is realizable as a graph.

Comment: Thanks.  
I was wondering when there would be a non-simple graph however. So I wonder why it was marked as duplicate with the corresponding link.